# Is it possible to set read-only for myself on unix?

Tags: bash, unix, file-permissions

<s>I have been given the address to a very large folder on a shared Unix server.</s> I've been given a path to some files on a unix server I'm working on through ssh. I don't want to waste space by creating a duplicate in my home area so I've linked the folder through `ln -s`. However I don't want to risk making any changes to the data within the folder.

How would I go about setting the files to read-only for myself? <s>Do I have to ask the owner of the folder/file? Do I need sudo access?</s> I am not the owner of the file and I do not have root access.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Thanks, [noted](https://superuser.com/questions/1258410/how-can-i-make-unix-directory-read-only-for-myself).

Answer (score 1):

Read about `chmod` command to change the mask on the files the *links point to*.

The owner or root can restrict access to files.

Also you probably need to mount that shared folder as read-only. But I am not sure how your folder is connected

**UPDATE**

The desired behaviour can be achieved using `mount` tool. ([man page for mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)).

> Note that the filesystem mount options will remain the same as those on the original mount point, and cannot be changed by passing the -o option along with --bind/--rbind. The mount options can be changed by a separate remount command, for example:
>
> `mount --bind olddir newdir`
>
> `mount -o remount,ro newdir`

[Here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=114041) is the similiar question to yours. Also solved via `mount` tool.

Comment: I know about `chmod`, but I asked the question as I'm neither the owner or have root access.

Comment: How is the folder connected to your computer? Is it mounted somehow or something?

Comment: It's not connected to my computer, I'm working through ssh on a server. The files are just in another area of the filesystem.

Comment: Presumably the 'address of' the very large folder was attached with a `mount` command to begin with. If you control the `mount`, then just pass the `-r` option when you mount the folder. (See `man 8 mount`)

Comment: The system I'm working on requires root access to use `mount`. So unfortunately this does not work for me.